# Persist login actions with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

How can i audit login actions with spring security and save them in the database, so for example i can retrieve the last logged in date for a specific user? Does spring offers this feature?
Thanks,

Comment: Spring Security publishes various `AbstractAuthenticationEvent`'s, e.g. `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`, `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent`, `LogoutSuccessEvent`, etc. You can register an `ApplicationListener` `@Bean` that is notified when these events occur and then perform audit logging. See the ref doc for `ApplicationListener`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#context-functionality-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement AuthenticationSuccessHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler and LogoutSuccessHandler. See dummy code below for refernce.

```
@Component("myAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
 
   
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) 
      throws IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            //update your repo or audit trail DB here.
        }
    }
}


    @Component("myLogoutSuccessHandler")
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session != null){
            // update DB
        }
    }
}
```

Also Spring Data JPA automatically persist the CreatedBy, CreatedDate, LastModifiedBy, and LastModifiedDate columns for any entity, internally which takes the user details from the Authentication Principal after successful autheitcation. You could leverage this as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so spring doesn't have a similar one by default?

Comment: Nothing out of the box, as plugin and play annotation. Does my answer serves your purpose?

Comment: Yes, your idea is the same as mine but i thought maybe spring offers one by default. Thanks